# "500 Internal Server Error" returned when sending GET request using HTTP Client in idea

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to test a Spring Boot project using HTTP Client of IDEA to send a GET request, but it return "**500 Internal Server Error**":

[image]

But under the same conditions, it is no problem to send by browser:

[image]

There's no problem using postman:

[image]

But using postwoman will cause a CORS problem. By default, postwoman run on port 3000, so I add `@CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:3000")` on the controller class. After that, there was no problem with the test:

[image]

At the same time, there is no problem sending GET request using VSCode's REST Client plug-in:

[image]

The controller class code is as follows:

[image]

It's confirmed that it's not a firewall problem, so is this a bug of HTTP Client?

Or does the HTTP client need to set some configuration?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from the logs

Comment: Please don't post your code as images. Instead, paste your code into code sections in your question.

Comment: When using the HTTP Client to send, Tomcat did not throw any exception. I feel that the HTTP Client cannot send it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a proxy problem. It is HTTP proxy set in IDEA. 500 is returned by the proxy server.

Comment: What proxy type do you use? Does it work when configure proxy in IDE settings?